# Emission sprite with color not showing in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have dots sprite which I want to become any other color. Default color is white and it's showing perfectly:
[image]

But when i try to add color, sprite is just gone:

[image]

How I could solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using Latest Unity or Updated Shaders.

My Unity Version

> Unity 2020.1.4f1

I had the same issue, the fix is simple.

In your **GlowColor Node**, you have set the value of your Color Alpha is set to **Zero**( In your default color box red you can see a small black color rectangular box that is your Alpha value which is set to ***zero***) set the Alpha value as **255** and the black box, becomes white and then your preview should display the red dots as you require.

How to change the Alpha Value:

1. Click on the Default color in the **GlowColor** Node
2. A Color Picker Pop up should appear.
3. Above the intensity slider you will see capital **A** change the value to **255**